# dataTaskWithURL doco, what does: error value of { NSURLErrorDomain, NSURLErrorCancelled } mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nserror

Say you're using NSURLSession dataTaskWithURL: ...

```
self.currentConnection =
  [sess dataTaskWithURL:goUrl
  completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
    [self.results addObjectsFromArray: [self yourDataConversionCode:data] ];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  if (after) after(); );
    }];
```

of course, if might need to cancel it.  (Say, the user has changed a search term, or similar problem.) That's easy with...

```
-(void)cancelAnyCurrentBooksearch
  {
  [self.currentConnection cancel];
  self.currentConnection = nil;
  }
```

However, stupidly it **still calls the completion block** which is very annoying.

Now, here's the "documentation" for cancel :

```
/* -cancel returns immediately, but marks a task as being canceled.
 * The task will signal -URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError: with an
 * error value of { NSURLErrorDomain, NSURLErrorCancelled }.
 */
- (void)cancel;
```

## Here's the problem...

What the hell does this mean:

**an error value of { NSURLErrorDomain, NSURLErrorCancelled }**

Can you have TWO values in an NSError??

If so, how do I check that the NSError was **exactly** this:

" { NSURLErrorDomain, NSURLErrorCancelled } "

whatever that means?

Note that if you do this:

```
self.currentConnection =
  [sess dataTaskWithURL:goUrl
  completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
    if( [error code] == NSURLErrorCancelled )
      {
      NSLog(@"  seemed to be CANCELLED programmatically?");
      return;
      }

    [self.results addObjectsFromArray: [self yourDataConversionCode:data] ];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  if (after) after(); );
    }];
```

It does "seem to work" - but it's hard to know of course.

So, how to check for this??

```
 * The task will signal -URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError: with an
 * error value of { NSURLErrorDomain, NSURLErrorCancelled }.
```

What does "two errors in curly braces" mean in documentation?

Does it mean **either** of those could happen?

I have no idea how one could determine the answer here for certain, it's undocumented.

Comment: Whoever down voted this is incredibly silly. The down voting on this site is just becoming ridiculous. It's getting to the point where if a question is highly technical people just down-vote it because they can't read properly and don't understand it. It's really absurd!

Comment: Voted up because people who vote down for no good reason annoy me, probably didn't like your colourful language.

Comment: HEH thanks Ryan - happy new year  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> An error value of { NSURLErrorDomain, NSURLErrorCancelled }
>
> Can you have TWO values in an NSError??

Yes. It's an object. It has properties. If you check [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you'll find it has both a `domain` and an `code` property.

If you wanted to check both, you'd do it as you might expect:

```
if ([error.domain isEqualToString:NSURLErrorDomain] && 
    error.code == NSURLErrorCancelled)
```

See the [Error Handling Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorObjectsDomains/ErrorObjectsDomains.html) for full details of error handling, including domains and codes.

Having said that, I think it's remotely improbable that anything *other* than NSURLErrorDomain is going to be associated with an NSURLSession data task completion handler with the code of NSURLErrorCancelled, so you should be fine just checking that as you are.

Comment: Ah! Brilliant, Matt!  It just didn't occur to me it was a domain.  What's with their freaky { } syntax?  (It has three properties - is it meant to be a pseudo struct syntax or something?!)  Thanks again!!!

Comment: Shit -- Matt, did you realise .domain is an NSString !!  I did not know that until now.

Comment: Because error.domain is a NSString, we should use if ([error.domain isEqualToString:NSURLErrorDomain] && error.code == NSURLErrorCancelled) instead.

Comment: @huntert Good point! I'd clearly been doing too much Swift when I answered this. Fixed.

Comment: Is there any possibility of getting this error code 'NSURLErrorCancelled', other than we cancel the task by '[task cancel];' ?